# PHP loop through variable with data from sqldb

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am making a html comparison table of total credit and debit for each month for the last one year.I am getting data from sql database table and using below code to segregate the data for each month.

Using below code, I am able to get the data and display on my html page. But I have to write separate similar code for each month. This is only a sample table, I have multiple similar code for different credit, debit category. so each time I have to duplicate it just like `$credit0,$credit1....$credit11`

I am new to php and this is how I come one with my limited knowledge. Is there any better way I can do it rather than writing multiple similar code for each month ?

```
<?php

//setting initial variable values are 0

$credit0 =$credit1 =$credit2 = 0;
$debit0  =$debit1  =$debit2 = 0;

//Getting 12 months details in Y-M format and assigning to different variable
$month0 = date("Y-M");
$month1 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-1 months"));
$month2 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-2 months"));
$month3 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-3 months"));
$month4 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-4 months"));
$month5 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-5 months"));
$month6 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-6 months"));
$month7 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-7 months"));
$month8 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-8 months"));
$month9 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-9 months"));
$month10 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-10 months"));
$month11 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-11 months"));

//Get the date details from sqldb and assgning to variable in Y-M format

$month_check= date('Y-M', strtotime($data['date'])); 

//each loop with the data from sqldb
foreach ($datas as $data){

    if ($month_check == $month0)  {

        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Credit') { $credit0 =  $credit0 + $data['amount']; }
        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Debit' ) { $debit0  =  $debit0  + $data['amount']; }   

    }

    if ($month_check == $month1)  {

        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Credit') { $credit1 =  $credit1 + $data['amount']; }
        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Debit' ) { $debit1  =  $debit1  + $data['amount']; }   

    }

    if ($month_check == $month2)  {

        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Credit') { $credit2 =  $credit2 + $data['amount']; }
        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Debit' ) { $debit2  =  $debit2  + $data['amount']; }   

    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    same format upto $month11
}

echo '<table"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Month</th>
               <th>Total Credit</th>
               <th>Total Debit</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$month0.'</td>
                <td>'.$credit0.'</td>
                <td>'.$debit0.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$month1.'</td>
                <td>'.$credit1.'</td>
                <td>'.$debit1.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$month2.'</td>
                <td>'.$credit2.'</td>
                <td>'.$debit2.'</td>
            </tr>
            .
            .
            .
            .
            upto $month11

        </tbody>

</table>';

//I have multiple similar tables for different categories

?>
```

**UPDATE:**
Using loop, I tried below method,but its not working properly

```
<?php

$credit0 =$credit1 =$credit2 = 0;
$debit0  =$debit1  =$debit2 = 0;

$month0 = date("Y-M");
$month1 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-1 months"));
$month2 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-2 months"));
$month3 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-3 months"));
$month4 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-4 months"));
$month5 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-5 months"));
$month6 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-6 months"));
$month7 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-7 months"));
$month8 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-8 months"));
$month9 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-9 months"));
$month10 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-10 months"));
$month11 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-11 months"));

$months = array($month0,$month1,$month2,$month3,$month4,$month5,$month6,$month7,$month8,$month9,$month10,$month11);
$nums = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);

foreach  (array_combine($months, $nums) as $month => $num) {

$month_check= date('Y-M', strtotime($data['date'])); 

foreach ($datas as $data){

    if ($month_check == $month)  {

        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Credit') { $credit.$num =  $credit.$num + $data['amount']; }
        if ($data['entry_type'] ==  'Debit' ) { $debit.$num  =  $debit.$num  + $data['amount']; }   

    }

}

echo '<table"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Month</th>
               <th>Total Credit</th>
               <th>Total Debit</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$month.$num.'</td>
                <td>'.$credit.$num.'</td>
                <td>'.$debit.$num.'</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

</table>';

}


?>
```

Comment: you need to loop ! please read that article : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm

Comment: Your updated code is wrong, you don't do array access with `.` in php, `.` is used for string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make a variable say $credit1. I though if I combine $credit $num values, I can make that

Answer (score 0):

Well first this:

```
$month0 = date("Y-M");
$month1 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-1 months"));
$month2 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-2 months"));
$month3 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-3 months"));
$month4 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-4 months"));
$month5 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-5 months"));
$month6 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-6 months"));
$month7 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-7 months"));
$month8 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-8 months"));
$month9 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-9 months"));
$month10 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-10 months"));
$month11 = date("Y-M", strtotime("-11 months"));

$months = array($month0,$month1,$month2,$month3,$month4,$month5,$month6,$month7,$month8,$month9,$month10,$month11);
$nums = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);
```

Becomes this:

```
$months = array();
$nums = array();

for($i=0; $i<12; $i++) {
     $month = date("Y-M", strtotime("-".$i." months"));
     array_push($months, $month);
     array_push($nums, $i);
}
```

And I don't really get what you're exactly trying to do with the rest of your code :|

Comment: I am trying to segregate data from db using above variable. In this example month0 represent current month and I need to get sum of all entries for credit and debit to variable credit0 and debit0. And repeat this till 12th month as month11